# can't stop syslogd on centos, sending constant messages

Tags: service

Syslogd sends messages on terminal and doesn't let operate normally. Commands can be run, but because there are constant messages I cannot see what I do.

Here the example of the message

```
kernel:[149036.521227] nf_ct_ftp: dropping packetIN= OUT=eth0 SRC=81.218.117.69 DST=5.29.251.78 LEN=53 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60231 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=21 DPT=62319 SEQ=3451322788 ACK=788682458 WINDOW=115 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 –
```

I tried `service syslog stop`, but without success. How do I stop the service?

Comment: Can you please show me the errors?

Answer (score 1):

found it: /etc/init.d/syslog stop